# what does "empahsis deleted" mean?

Tags: meaning

For example, it appears in the picture below and usually in the follow of the word" Ibid".So what does this word mean? [image]

Comment: Please visit [writers.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

Text in the original quoted material had certain words emphasized (underlined, italicized, or in bold) but, for whatever reason, the author chose to put the text in roman—removing the emphasis. The notation indicates that the original material has been altered in this way.

This is the opposite of what is normally done.

The *Chicago Manual of Style* (13.62):

> An author wishing to call particular attention to a word or phrase in
>   quoted material may italicize it but must tell readers what has been
>   done, by means of such formulas as “italics mine,” “italics added,”
>   “emphasis added,” or “emphasis mine.” Occasionally it may be important
>   to point out that italics in a quotation were indeed in the original.
>   Here the usual phrase is “italics in the original” or, for example,
>   “De Quincey’s italics.” This information appears either in parentheses
>   following the quotation or in a source note to the quotation. If there
>   are italics in the original of the passage quoted, the information is
>   best enclosed in brackets and placed directly after the added italics.
>   Consistency in method throughout a work is essential.

[Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/emphasis-added.html):

> Author's or reviewer's note (enclosed usually in square brackets)
>   after a quote to indicate that he or she has emphasized certain words
>   by bolding, italicizing, or underlining them. Sometimes the term
>   'emphasis mine' is used instead.

Interestingly, I cannot easily locate a style guide that mentions the particular use of *removing* emphasis from quoted material. Nonetheless, the notation follows the general convention for such alteration.

I was able to locate [a note](http://www.sscnet.ucla.edu/polisci/faculty/anderson/quotation.htm) from a professor at UCLA, in which he instructs students on how to use this notation:

> All quotations must be exact, except that you may interpolate words
>   enclosed in square brackets ("[ ]"), excise words by replacing them
>   with ellipsis ("..."), and underline or italicize for emphasis by
>   adding in square brackets “emphasis supplied” or delete the author’s
>   underlining or italicization by adding in square brackets “emphasis
>   deleted.”

---

Note: This has nothing to do with **Ibid**. That word is used in citations. Per *Chicago*:

> The abbreviation *ibid*. (from *ibidem*, “in the same place”) usually
>   refers to a single work cited in the note immediately preceding.

So, **Ibid**. essentially means "the source of this material is the same as previously referenced." The use of **Ibid**. has fallen out of favour recently, with the preference now being to simply repeat the last name of the author. For example, in the picture you provided, it would be replaced with "Grisez"—and that would refer to "Grisez, *CMP*," not "Grisez and Shaw."

Comment: "**Ibid** has fallen out of favour recently" except on various SE sites (not ELU) where I learnt about it from. I say "various SE sites", but it's probably more down to particular high rep community members on those sites.